# How to run swift 1.2 code on an iOS 9.1 device?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9, xcode6.4

I'm trying to make an app in Swift 1.2. Obviously, Swift 2.0 introduced a lot of changes but before I migrate the whole project over, I would like to be able to test it while being still on 1.2.
But my iPhone is now running iOS9.1 and my Xcode 6.4 doesn't seem to recognize the iPhone for me to test.

Is there any way to run my Swift 1.2 project on my iPhone running iOS9.1? Or do I need to downgrade my iPhone in order to test the 1.2 project?

Comment: @MZubairShamshad Yeah, but Xcode7 or newer doesn't let you compile in Swift 1.2, so I would have to migrate the project to swift 2 to use that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want. But you need to take a few steps. You can get Xcode 6 to recognize your iOS device with iOS 9 but in order to do so, you need to install Xcode 7.1 and run it. Then connect your iOS device. Once Xcode 7.1 has recognized your iOS device with iOS 9 and processed its symbols you can exit Xcode 7.1 and start Xcode 6.4. Open your Swift 1.2 project and you should now be able to test on the iOS 9.1 device.

Before installing Xcode 7.1, rename your Xcode 6.4 application. For example, go to Applications and rename Xcode to Xcode6.4. This will allow Xcode 7.1 to be installed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your device with apple account and then create archive .ipa file on your machine and then using http://www.diawi.com/ this link to upload your .ipa file and generated link past in your phone browser and install it.

Comment: You don't need a website to install an IPA. Just use iTunes on your own computer.